# Java/Apache HTTP Client - How to get POST URL redirects chain

Tags: java, apache, rest, httpclient, redirect

I'm consuming a REST service by sending a POST request, the response returns a 302 status code and contains a 'Location' header which points to the new location of the resource. When sending the request on Chrome's Advanced Rest Client it shows all the redirect URLs as Redirect #1 #2 #3.

The problem is there are 2 redirect URLs (sometimes 3) and I cannot get the redirect chain to get the second one's Location header which is the only one that works without cookies on any browser.

Can someone please walk me through on how to get the chain of redirect URLs?
Thanks in advance!

```
protected HttpEntity sendPost(String url, String contentType) throws Exception
{
    logger.info("Sending SSO parameters to " + url);

    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().disableRedirectHandling().build();

    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    if (contentType != null)
    {
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", contentType);
    }

    UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(formparams);

    httpPost.setEntity(entity);

    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

    StatusLine s = response.getStatusLine();

    if (validateResponseStatusCode)
    {
        if (s.getStatusCode() != 200 && s.getStatusCode() != 201)
        {
            logger.debug("Error on POST request. REST procedure returned status " + s.getStatusCode() + " "
                    + response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());

            throw new Exception("Error executing REST procedure. Returned status is: " + s.getStatusCode() + " "
                    + response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
        }
    }

    redirectLocationURL = getHeaderValue(RestHeader.Location, response);

    statusCode = s.getStatusCode();

    return response.getEntity();
}

protected String getHeaderValue(RestHeader headerName, HttpResponse response)
{
    String headerValue = "";

    logger.info("Getting header '" + headerName + "'");

    for (Header currentHeader : response.getAllHeaders())
    {
        if (currentHeader.getName().equals(headerName.toString()))
        {
            headerValue = currentHeader.getValue();
            logger.info("'" + headerName + "' header value is: " + headerValue);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (headerValue.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
    {
        logger.info("Header '" + headerName + "' not found in HTTP Response");
        return null;
    }

    return headerValue;
}
```